# Sharer.php fetches wrong html

Tags: html, facebook-sharer

When i try to share this
http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2F11E4n6g&t=A.T.%26B.+SRL
the content from http://www.biofach.de/de/ will be displayed in the post.

http://bit.ly/11E4n6g
actually links to 
http://m.biofach.de/de/ausstellersuche/?focus=exhibitor&focus2=155689&focus3=bio13
which has og:description and og:image but is not loaded.

We have a redirect for non mobile devices, but it should be disabled for user-agents with "Facebook|Twitter|Bitly|Xing|Tweet".
This behaviour can be emulated with
http://m.biofach.de/de/ausstellersuche/?focus=exhibitor&focus2=155689&focus3=bio13&dononmobileredirect=false

The Link on my facebook page will be correct, but the text/image is not from the desired page but from some redirected page.

Now i do not even see the redirected request in my log file anymore.
Where does facebook get the incorrect data?

Thank you for your help

Comment: take a look at: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object (enter your bit.ly url and you can see what's happening)

Comment: Thank you very much !!!
The canonical is not mobile. Doh!

Comment: If you've managed to fix your issue, feel free to post it as an answer and then mark it as correct :)

Comment: Keep in mind that Facebook's `sharer.php` endpoint is officially deprecated and could disappear at any time.

Comment: @cpilko what endpoint is recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Prisoner:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object

can help trace the routes a sharer url is fetched for display.